Orbit Camera In vulkan
I've been having trouble trying to make a solidworks style Orbit Camera, nothing I do seems to work even though apparently it should (I've tried multiple methods and this seems to be the most promising).
I have a camera struct defined as such
Camera :: struct {
    pos:vec3 = .{0,0,1}; // 1
    target:vec3 = .{0,0,0};

    up:vec3 = .{0,0,1};
    right:vec3 = .{1,0,0};
    // zoom:float = 1;

    Tmat:mat4 = IDENTITY; // Translation
    Rmat:mat4 = IDENTITY; // Rotation
    Pmat:mat4 = IDENTITY; // Pivot matrix
    
    view:mat4 = IDENTITY;
    viewMat:mat4 = IDENTITY; // really inverse view mat

    lastposx:float;
    lastposy:float;
}

my rotate camera function is defined as such
rotate_cam :: (r:fwdpp_r,cam:*Camera,x:float,y:float) {
    using cam;
    rotation_origin := target;

    dx := TAU / r.pipeline.Extent.width;
    dy := PI / r.pipeline.Extent.height;
    r_x := (lastposx - x) * dx;
    r_y := (lastposy - y) * dy;
    lastposx = x;
    lastposy = y;
    rotx:Quaternion = .{r_x,0,0,1};
    roty:Quaternion = .{0,0,r_y,1};

    camDir := normalize(pos - target);

    right = xx normalize(cross(up,camDir));
    up = xx normalize(cross(camDir,right));

    rq := rotx * roty;

    Rmat = rotate(Rmat,rq);


    updateViewMatrix(cam);
}

with rotate being
rotate :: (q: Quaternion) -> Matrix4 {
    m: Matrix4;



    xs := q.x * 2;
    ys := q.y * 2;
    zs := q.z * 2;

    wx := q.w * xs;
    wy := q.w * ys;
    wz := q.w * zs;

    _xx := q.x * xs;
    xy := q.x * ys;
    xz := q.x * zs;

    yy := q.y * ys;
    yz := q.y * zs;
    zz := q.z * zs;

    m._11 = 1.0 - (yy + zz);
    m._12 = xy - wz;
    m._13 = xz + wy;

    m._21 = xy + wz;
    m._22 = 1.0 - (_xx + zz);
    m._23 = yz - wx;

    m._31 = xz - wy;
    m._32 = yz + wx;
    m._33 = 1.0 - (_xx + yy);
    
    m._44 = 1;

    return m;
}

update_view matrix being
updateViewMatrix :: (cam:*Camera) {
    using cam;
    Pmat = translate(IDENTITY,target);
    viewMat = multiply(TO_VULKAN_COORDS_MATRIX,inverse(Pmat) * Rmat * Pmat * Tmat);
    view = inverse(viewMat);
}

TO_VULKAN_COORDS_MATRIX :: Matrix4.{
    0, -1,  0,  0,
    0,  0, -1,  0,
    1,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  1,
};

This produces this result

I figured it out, rather than doing this whole mathy solution, instead we can just translate from a spherical coordinate system to a cartesian one like so:
from_spherical_coords :: (v:vec3) -> vec3 {
    radius:float = v.x;
    theta:float = v.y;
    phi:float = v.z;

    x := cos(theta) * sin(phi) * radius;
    y := sin(theta) * sin(phi) * radius;
    z := sin(phi) * radius;
    return .{x,y,z};
}

Camera :: struct {
    Spos:vec3 = .{1,0,0}; 
    /*
        X = radius
        Y = theta
        Z = phi
    */
    Cpos:vec3 = .{0,0,0};

    target:vec3 = .{0,0,0};

    viewMat:mat4 = IDENTITY;

    lastposx:float;
    lastposy:float;
}

rotate_cam :: (r:fwdpp_r,cam:*Camera,x:float,y:float) {
    using cam;

    Spos.y = (lastposx - x) / r.pipeline.Extent.width;
    Spos.z = (lastposy - y)/ r.pipeline.Extent.height;
    print("%\n",Spos);
    Cpos = from_spherical_coords(Spos);
    
    updateViewMatrix(cam);
}

zoom :: (cam:*Camera,zoom:float) {
    using cam;
    Spos.x += zoom;
    Cpos = from_spherical_coords(Spos);
    updateViewMatrix(cam);
    
}

updateViewMatrix :: (cam:*Camera) {
    using cam;
    // Cpos = from_spherical_coords(Spos);
    viewMat = look_at_matrix(Cpos,target,.{0,0,1});
}
```

